# What reaction does happen when molten sodium hydroxide reacts with aluminium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, metal

The reaction between aqueous sodium hydroxide and aluminium  follows this equation:
$$\ce{2NaOH + 2H2O + 2Al = 2NaAlO2 + 3H2}$$
But it's obviously not possible to balance this equation without the water included and so I'd like to know what is the reaction of only sodium hydroxide and aluminium? (in this reaction the sodium hydroxide/aluminium has to be molten to react). I tried searching for any info on this reaction but i couldn't find anything.

I've then tried melting a small piece of aluminium and putting a single pellet of sodium hydroxide on top of it (i had to melt the aluminium instead of the sodium hydroxide because molten sodium hydroxide attacks almost everything including glass). The reaction produced a flammable gas that immediately ignited which was probably hydrogen. I'd like to know what the equation of this reaction is and what are all the products.

I'm once again saying that this reaction is **not** the reaction of aluminium and aqueous sodium hydroxide solution, but the reaction of aluminium and **molten** sodium hydroxide which means that the water is absent in the equation.

The equation is probably $\ce{2Al + 6NaOH ⟶ 2Na3AlO3 + 3H2}$ but I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: Proposition :  $\ce{2 Al + 6 NaOH  -> 2 Na3AlO3 + 3 H2}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does aluminium react with bases to form aluminates?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50447/how-does-aluminium-react-with-bases-to-form-aluminates)

Comment: @NilayGhosh  The referred question  addresses the aquaeous scenario, what is not the case here.

Comment: @Maurice I agree. According to one source it reacts with water following this equation: Na3AlO3 + 3 H2O → 3 NaOH + Al(OH)3 but i'm not sure if that's true. Could be also Na3AlO3 + H2O → NaAlO2 + 2NaOH     Edit: the outcome is gonna be sodium aluminate (NaAlO2) in both cases because the sodium hydroxide will react with the sodium hydroxide.

Comment: There are multiple cases of anhydrous [sodium aluminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_aluminate)

Comment: @Poutnik well anhydrous sodium aluminate is NaAlO2 and hydrated sodium aluminate is NaAl(OH)4 but both of them are made from the reaction of aluminium and sodium hydroxide solution and not aluminium and sodium hydroxide reaction.

Comment: *Other related compounds, sometimes called sodium aluminate, prepared by reaction of Na2O and Al2O3 are Na5AlO4 which contains discrete AlO45− anions, Na7Al3O8 and Na17Al5O16 which contain complex polymeric anions, and NaAl11O17, once mistakenly believed to be β-alumina, a phase of aluminium oxide.*

Comment: Do you know how dry your NaOH was?

Comment: Still another possibility: with excess sodium you could form sodium hydride, which is stable up to 638C ([WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_hydride)) and thus compatible with molten NaOH. Such a reaction could take the form  2NaOH +Al -> NaAlO2 + NaH +(1/2) H2.

Comment: @Snijderfrey the melting point of sodium hydroxide is just above 300°C so all the water should've just evaporated.